# Обработка динамического JSON в Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Имеется метод в сервисе:

```
@DELETE("api/rest/dir/{dir_path}/")
Call<BaseResponse> delete(@Path("dir_path") String dirPath);
```

В виде ответа могут придти разные JSON.

```
{
"dir": { "status": "success" }
}
```

или

```
{
"dir": {
"error_code": "{error number}",
"error_message": "{description or error}"
}
}
```

Соответственно имеются классы:

```
public class BaseResponse {
}



public class Error extends BaseResponse {
@SerializedName("error_code")
private int errorCode;

@SerializedName("error_message")
private String errorMessage;




public class Status extends BaseResponse {
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;
```

Как правильно обрабатывать ответы? А то всегда в response находится BaseResponse и не приводится ни к одному из двух наследующих его типов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классы менять не нужно, класс остаётся один и тот же, только в случае успешного ответа в `status` возвращается **success**, а ваши `error` будут `null`, и наоборот в случае ответа с ошибкой - `status == null`, а в `error` будут данные:

```
public class AwesomeResponse extends ErrorResponse {

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    // сколько угодно полей

}

public class ErrorResponse {

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("error_code")
    public Integer errorCode;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("error_message")
    public String errorMessage;

}
```

Comment: А это единственный вариант?
Просто я привел простейший пример.
И есть другие случаи, где может придти например error или какой-то json с большим количеством полей. И тогда будет не очень удобно, как мне кажется.

Comment: @Rick, в таком случае у вас будет POJO с неким большим количеством полей, допустим `PersonResponse`. Так же сделайте `ErrorResponse` с полями `error_code` и `error_message`. После этого просто наследуйте `PersonResponse` от `ErrorResponse`. Так как сделали вы - абсолютно неправильно. Происходит десериализация ответа в объект класса BaseResponse, который у вас не содержит полей.

Comment: @Rick, дополнил ответ

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Сейчас попробую так сделать.